# Spring CSRF token issue

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, csrf

I'm testing the upload file using spring mvc 4.  I have this jsp file to upload a file:

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/create/uploadFile" ></c:url>
<form method= "POST" action="${addAction}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
</form>
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    Print successful and start process ....
}
```

I'm getting this error when I click submit

```
Invalid CSRF Token &#39;null&#39; was found on the request parameter &#39;_csrf&#39; or header &#39;X-CSRF-TOKEN&#39;.
```

What I don't understand is in my login page.  I use the same process and it works, I can login and go to the upload page.  login.jsp:

```
<form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />

     username and password and submit ....
</form>
```

My spring security:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/home**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/home" 
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
    <csrf />
</http>
```

Any idea why it works on the login.jsp and not in create upload.?

I also tried binding the upload form in a model and using form:form but still doesn't work.

Comment: To my knowledge, csrf token is used while login & logout. Why do you need it in UpLoadFile Post submission ?

Comment: Have you done what is mentioned in the Spring Security [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-multipart)?

Comment: @kswaughs CSRF definitively doesn't only apply to login/logout.